# How can I secure bluetooth paring with no display device?

Tags: android, security, bluetooth, display

I want to secure bluetooth paring in android with no display device.

Is this possible? I think that secure bluetooth paring with no display device is impossible even if android has display.

How can I do this? How can I protect this paring?

I can develop no display device and android.

Please tell me about a way.

Answer (score 0):

Secure pairing with devices which has No Display is possible, you can check that almost all bluetooth headsets have no display but they are securely paired with Android devices. In your device, you need to set your device capability as "NoInputNoOutput"

Comment: http://www.inc.com/joseph-steinberg/are-your-bluetooth-devices-secure-maybe-not.html